# Xamarin UI Test Select menu options after after app.PressMenu is clicked

Tags: android, xamarin

Tapping the visible menu items is not a problem for example while testing a Android application.

```
app.Tap(x => x.Marked("menu_home"));
```

However on some pages a few of the menu items are hidden behind the 3 dots and I can reveal the menu items with

```
app.PressMenu
```

But what I cannot seem to do is select a menu option from those that are shown in the popup menu.

Can anyone show me an example on how to deal with this please. Many thanks

Comment: Could you show me the screenshot for what you want and what it is? I would try to reproduce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer thanks.

```
    app.PressMenu();
    app.Tap(x => x.Text("Select Menu Item"));
```